# Host machine app unable to query guest machine Cassandra database

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

**Environment**

Host:

- Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop 64Bit
- Visual Studio Code + CassandraCSharpDriver

Guest:

- Ubuntu 18.04 Server 64Bit
- Java and Cassandra installed
- Single node
- Replication 1
- Consistency 1
- Cassandra service running
- keyspace and table created
- Data entered into table
- Virtual Box network for guest set to Bridge.

---

**The problem**

When I run the code on the host machine, I get an error:

```
user@desktop:~/Desktop/vsc$ dotnet run
Unhandled exception. Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts tried for query failed (tried 192.168.0.15:9042: SocketException 'No route to host')
   at Cassandra.Connections.ControlConnection.Connect(Boolean isInitializing)
   at Cassandra.Connections.ControlConnection.InitAsync()
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToCompleteAsync(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Cassandra.SessionManagement.IInternalCluster.OnInitializeAsync()
   at Cassandra.ClusterLifecycleManager.InitializeAsync()
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Cassandra.SessionManagement.IInternalCluster.ConnectAsync[TSession](ISessionFactory`1 sessionFactory, String keyspace)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.ConnectAsync(String keyspace)
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete[T](Task`1 task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Connect(String keyspace)
   at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/user/Desktop/vsc/Program.cs:line 15
user@desktop:~/Desktop/vsc$
```

---

**What I have tried**

On a Windows machine where the machine runs the code and Cassandra on the same host without using a VM, the code and the database work fine as the code is able to insert and select from the database without any issues.

I can ping both directions without a problem and traceroute returns the following:

Basic:

```
user@desktop:~$ traceroute 192.168.0.15
traceroute to 192.168.0.15 (192.168.0.15), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  node1 (192.168.0.15)  0.737 ms  0.694 ms  0.697 ms
user@desktop:~$
```

With port:

```
user@desktop:~$ traceroute 192.168.0.15 -p 9042
traceroute to 192.168.0.15 (192.168.0.15), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  node1 (192.168.0.15)  0.386 ms  0.388 ms  0.422 ms
user@desktop:~$
```

Opened the port number in the guest VM `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9042 -j ACCEPT`

Now getting the following error message:

```
user@desktop:~/Desktop/vsc$ dotnet run
Unhandled exception. Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts tried for query failed (tried 192.168.0.15:9042: SocketException 'Connection refused')
   at Cassandra.Connections.ControlConnection.Connect(Boolean isInitializing)
   at Cassandra.Connections.ControlConnection.InitAsync()
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToCompleteAsync(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Cassandra.SessionManagement.IInternalCluster.OnInitializeAsync()
   at Cassandra.ClusterLifecycleManager.InitializeAsync()
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Cassandra.SessionManagement.IInternalCluster.ConnectAsync[TSession](ISessionFactory`1 sessionFactory, String keyspace)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.ConnectAsync(String keyspace)
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete(Task task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete[T](Task`1 task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Cluster.Connect(String keyspace)
   at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/user/Desktop/vsc/Program.cs:line 15
user@desktop:~/Desktop/vsc$
```

---

**Question**

How do I configure the VM guest so I can get the code on the host machine to connect to the Cassandra database?  I am assuming the issue is happening because the VM is not configured properly?

I connect to the server using 192.168.0.15, but internally the server seems to use 127.0.0.1.  Do I need to forward any incoming connections to 127.0.0.1?  How do I check if that is the case and how do I forward the port if needed?  As when I was testing the code in Windows where the code and the server were the same machine, I was connecting to the local port 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I see a "`SocketException 'No route to host'`" Error Message. Try also a trace route and see what it says, beside the ping.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, traceroute details added above.

Comment: Can you check if there is any kind of problem related to the `9042` Port?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, added `-p 9042` to the traceroute command and it seems find.  Please see output above.

Comment: What is your `dotnet` Version? Can you update it somehow toward its latest possible patch?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, dotnet version is 3.0.100.  I have just done `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9042 -j ACCEPT` in the guest vm.  Now when I try the code, instead of `No route to host`, I get a `Connection Refused` error message.

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, as far as I can tell from this link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core I have the latest stable dotnet installed.  Anything newer would be a preview version of dotnet and not stable.

Comment: I would go on a _MicroSoft_ Forum, try to find someone who has been fiddling around with the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ _.Net_ Framework on the _Ubuntu_ Operating System and then I would repost my question there. For instance, I would try the _MicroSoft_ _Answers_ Community and I would select the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ _.Net_ Framework Category. Also, I would slide on the _Stack Exchange_ Web-Site more specifically toward the _Ask Ubuntu_ Web-Site and then I would repost my question there.